# Grammar to parse sql statements delimited by semicolon in antlr4

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I'm looking to separate sql statements that could have comments /* */ or strings 'test' or line comments --line comment (sql style) separated by semicolons. An example would be:

```
Blah blah 'string ; ' ;
More text /* semicolon(;) inside comment */
Some more text 
in multiple lines
```

the text above should retrieve only two statements since the semicolon inside the string ' ' and the comment /* */ should not count as a delimiter.
The current grammar I have is :

```
grammar SqlStatements;

sql_stmts:
    text (';' text)* EOF
    ;

text:
     SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT*
    | STRING* 
    | TEXT* 
;

TEXT:
 ~['--';\''/*']* 
;

STRING
: 
     '\'' ('\'\''|~'\'')* '\''

;

SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT
 : '--' ~[\r\n]* 
 ;

MULTILINE_COMMENT
 : '/*' .*? ( '*/' | EOF ) 
 ;
```

The code above crashes when typing *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when Mike's answer was fine, I needed to create the grammar in antlr. The following grammar worked for me:

```
sql_stmts:
    sql_stmt (';'+ sql_stmt)*
    ;

sql_stmt:
    TEXT*
;
TEXT:
~[']
| STRING
;
BLOCK_COMMENT
: '/*' .*? ( '*/' | EOF ) -> channel(HIDDEN)
;
LINE_COMMENT
: '--' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN)
;
SPACES
 : [ \u000B\t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN)
 ;

STRING
: 
     '\'' ('\'\''|~'\'')* '\'' 
;
```

Answer (score 2):

The common approach for parsing SQL is to first split the individual statements. That might involve handling of delimiter switches, which is needed e.g. when you have a stored procedure in the dump which must be handled as a whole but needs the semicolon as internal statement delimiter.

This can be done very quickly with an optimized loop that jumps over comments and strings. Here's code how this is handled in [MySQL Workbench](http://mysqlworkbench.org):

```cpp
/**
 * A statement splitter to take a list of sql statements and split them into individual statements,
 * return their position and length in the original string (instead the copied strings).
 */
size_t MySQLParserServicesImpl::determineStatementRanges(const char *sql, size_t length,
                                                         const std::string &initial_delimiter,
                                                         std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t> > &ranges,
                                                         const std::string &line_break)
{
  _stop = false;
  std::string delimiter = initial_delimiter.empty() ? ";" : initial_delimiter;
  const unsigned char *delimiter_head = (unsigned char*)delimiter.c_str();

  const unsigned char keyword[] = "delimiter";

  const unsigned char *head = (unsigned char *)sql;
  const unsigned char *tail = head;
  const unsigned char *end = head + length;
  const unsigned char *new_line = (unsigned char*)line_break.c_str();
  bool have_content = false; // Set when anything else but comments were found for the current statement.

  while (!_stop && tail < end)
  {
    switch (*tail)
    {
      case '/': // Possible multi line comment or hidden (conditional) command.
        if (*(tail + 1) == '*')
        {
          tail += 2;
          bool is_hidden_command = (*tail == '!');
          while (true)
          {
            while (tail < end && *tail != '*')
              tail++;
            if (tail == end) // Unfinished comment.
              break;
            else
            {
              if (*++tail == '/')
              {
                tail++; // Skip the slash too.
                break;
              }
            }
          }

          if (!is_hidden_command && !have_content)
            head = tail; // Skip over the comment.
        }
        else
          tail++;

        break;

      case '-': // Possible single line comment.
      {
        const unsigned char *end_char = tail + 2;
        if (*(tail + 1) == '-' && (*end_char == ' ' || *end_char == '\t' || is_line_break(end_char, new_line)))
        {
          // Skip everything until the end of the line.
          tail += 2;
          while (tail < end && !is_line_break(tail, new_line))
            tail++;
          if (!have_content)
            head = tail;
        }
        else
          tail++;

        break;
      }

      case '#': // MySQL single line comment.
        while (tail < end && !is_line_break(tail, new_line))
          tail++;
        if (!have_content)
          head = tail;
        break;

      case '"':
      case '\'':
      case '`': // Quoted string/id. Skip this in a local loop.
      {
        have_content = true;
        char quote = *tail++;
        while (tail < end && *tail != quote)
        {
          // Skip any escaped character too.
          if (*tail == '\\')
            tail++;
          tail++;
        }
        if (*tail == quote)
          tail++; // Skip trailing quote char to if one was there.

        break;
      }

      case 'd':
      case 'D':
      {
        have_content = true;

        // Possible start of the keyword DELIMITER. Must be at the start of the text or a character,
        // which is not part of a regular MySQL identifier (0-9, A-Z, a-z, _, $, \u0080-\uffff).
        unsigned char previous = tail > (unsigned char *)sql ? *(tail - 1) : 0;
        bool is_identifier_char = previous >= 0x80
        || (previous >= '0' && previous <= '9')
        || ((previous | 0x20) >= 'a' && (previous | 0x20) <= 'z')
        || previous == '$'
        || previous == '_';
        if (tail == (unsigned char *)sql || !is_identifier_char)
        {
          const unsigned char *run = tail + 1;
          const unsigned char *kw = keyword + 1;
          int count = 9;
          while (count-- > 1 && (*run++ | 0x20) == *kw++)
            ;
          if (count == 0 && *run == ' ')
          {
            // Delimiter keyword found. Get the new delimiter (everything until the end of the line).
            tail = run++;
            while (run < end && !is_line_break(run, new_line))
              run++;
            delimiter = base::trim(std::string((char *)tail, run - tail));
            delimiter_head = (unsigned char*)delimiter.c_str();

            // Skip over the delimiter statement and any following line breaks.
            while (is_line_break(run, new_line))
              run++;
            tail = run;
            head = tail;
          }
          else
            tail++;
        }
        else
          tail++;

        break;
      }

      default:
        if (*tail > ' ')
          have_content = true;
        tail++;
        break;
    }

    if (*tail == *delimiter_head)
    {
      // Found possible start of the delimiter. Check if it really is.
      size_t count = delimiter.size();
      if (count == 1)
      {
        // Most common case. Trim the statement and check if it is not empty before adding the range.
        head = skip_leading_whitespace(head, tail);
        if (head < tail)
          ranges.push_back(std::make_pair<size_t, size_t>(head - (unsigned char *)sql, tail - head));
        head = ++tail;
        have_content = false;
      }
      else
      {
        const unsigned char *run = tail + 1;
        const unsigned char *del = delimiter_head + 1;
        while (count-- > 1 && (*run++ == *del++))
          ;

        if (count == 0)
        {
          // Multi char delimiter is complete. Tail still points to the start of the delimiter.
          // Run points to the first character after the delimiter.
          head = skip_leading_whitespace(head, tail);
          if (head < tail)
            ranges.push_back(std::make_pair<size_t, size_t>(head - (unsigned char *)sql, tail - head));
          tail = run;
          head = run;
          have_content = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Add remaining text to the range list.
  head = skip_leading_whitespace(head, tail);
  if (head < tail)
    ranges.push_back(std::make_pair<size_t, size_t>(head - (unsigned char *)sql, tail - head));

  return 0;
}
```

This works well also for large sql scripts and can split a dump containing 1 million lines in about 1 second (depends of course on the box you run this on). The var _stop is a flag used to allow breaking the split process. The code is handling MySQL code, so it properly handles hidden commands (version comments).

With the start and length info per query you can now go to your parser.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't ignore the warning and error messages generated when compiling the grammar.

Second, the TEXT rule does not do what you think it does -- quotes don't work there.  See the [doc](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules#LexerRules-LexerRuleElements).

Third, your first line of input is actually TEXT STRING TEXT SEMI.  That second TEXT is the space before your SEMI rule, yet your rule only allows for a single non-consecutive occurrence of TEXT before the SEMI.